# How to make ../../ [parent] prefix work or not be ignored on src/ng-src in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, angularjs-directive

I am trying to bind an image `$scope.imageLocation = /var/mock-dirs/image.jpg` from a directory that resides a couple of levels above app's root dir.

```
<img src="{{'../../../'+imageLocation}}" [...]
```

However, I can see that the `../../../` prefix part is being ignored and removed from the resolved address and my app tries to access the image at `http://localhost:9000/var/mock-dirs/image.jpg`.

I also tried prefixing the image in the controller - getting the same result.

What am I doing wrong? Is it the expected behaviour? How can I overcome it?

PS: Though it is most likely not the reason for the path being overwritten, there is a read access on the whole path to the image, e.g., `/var/mock-dirs/`.

PPS: When I try to paste the full path (with `../`'s part) directly into the Chrome's address bar - same thing happens - `../`'s are being removed

Comment: Is your app root directory also the the root of your web server or are you using a virtual directory for your app?

Comment: Nope, it is not the same dir as the web server.

Comment: can you tell me little more about your setup?  Dev or prod env?  How do you you run this app (as a server)?  Why is your image folder not in your web folder?

Comment: Definitely :) It is a Java application (the backend is written in Java) for which I am adding a "front end". A user selects and sends some images for processing to the backend, which in return stores them under the `/var` directory. After all the processing is done - I am trying to access processed images from the front end for displaying to a user.

Comment: I realize that there are security concerns with this sort of an access ( directly via var), but that is my temporarily solution until the API gets extended to support a `GET` request to return the needed image. Also, I was trying to rewrite/encode URL value of `../` via `..%2F` and some other ways - but in vain (even though the 'encoded' path remains and is not being overwritten in browser
)

Comment: Also, tried using `encodeURIComponent` to encode the image path, and it was essentially the same as `..%2F`